# Swagger Controller Mappings

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

With Swagger-UI I am trying to display methods that have the same base URL underneath one Swagger container regardless of which controller they fall under. Imagine this code.

```
// Current Swagger Config Class
@Bean
public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
      .select()                                  
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
      .paths(getPaths())                          
      .build()
      .apiInfo(getApiInfo());                                       
}

private Predicate<String> getPaths(){
    return or(regex("/attributes.*"),
              regex("/other.*"));
}

// Controller 1
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/attributes")
@Api(value = "User Attribute Services", description = "User Attributes API")
public class UserAttributesController {

    @Autowired
    private UserAttributesService userService;
    @Autowired
    private UserAttributeValidator userAttributeValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/search", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public List<User> searchUser(@RequestBody List<UserDTO> userDTOList){
        // meaningless implementation ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean insertUser(@RequestBody List<UserDTO> userDTOList){
        // meaningless implementation ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/update{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public boolean updateUser(@PathVariable id, @RequestBody UserDTO updateDetails){
        // meaningless implementation ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public boolean deleteUser(@PathVariable id){
        // meaningless implementation ...
    }
}

// Controller 2
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/attributes")
@Api(value = "Tech Attribute Services", description = "Tech Attributes API")
public class TechAttributesController {

    @Autowired
    private TechAttributesService techService;
    @Autowired
    private TechAttributeValidator techAttributeValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tech/search", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public List<Tech> searchTech(@RequestBody List<TechDTO> techDTOList){
        // meaningless implementation ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tech/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean insertTech(@RequestBody List<TechDTO> techDTOList){
        // meaningless implementation ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tech/update{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public boolean updateTech(@PathVariable id, @RequestBody TechDTO updateDetails){
        // meaningless implementation ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tech/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public boolean deleteTech(@PathVariable id){
        // meaningless implementation ...
    }
}
```

My application swagger page is displaying the attributes underneath seperate containers. Eventhough I specified the regex path of '/attributes' in my Swagger Configuration the fact that these are in different controllers is overriding what I want. If I put all these methods into 1 controller I get the desired result, but this is only a subset of the attribute classes I have and I do not want a massive controller that spans over 1k lines.

Extra: If you noticed the services are almost identical for the attributes. I have been trying to find a clever way of declaring them once and simply overriding the method declations instead of redefining similiar services over again, but because the @RequestMapping annotation needs to be a constant value I could not find a way to change the annotation depending on the implementation rather than the declaration.

[Swagger-UI Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lu3Q.png)